# Access Quick Tools Toolbar in Adobe Acrobat XI using applescript

Tags: applescript, acrobat

I'm writing applescript to automate acrobat. I'm trying to find  UI element inside Quick Tools Toolbar in Adobe Acrobat XI.

I have no problem accessing menu bar:

```
tell menu "Tools" of menu item "Tools" of the menu "View" of menu bar 1 
return UI elements
end tell
```

But I can't some reason find a way to access Quick Tools Toolbar buttoms.

[image: Adobe Acrobat Quick Tools Toolbar]

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Max, I got it finally:
I created JS file with simple code

```
app.addMenuItem({cName:"Convert Colors", cParent:"View", cExec:'app.execMenuItem("ColorConversionMenuItem");'});
```

and I added it into acrobat (USER/Library/Application Support/Adobe/Acrobat/11.0/JavaScripts/).

I enabled menu items JavaScript execution privileges in Acrobat Preferences.

Now I can open "Convert Colors" from main menu bar, and create applescript which do the same.

Answer (score 2):

I did a quick check using UI Browser, and the closest UI element I could get to a toolbutton is the the quick toolbar as such. Its role is "unknown", and it has no more children. Example (as suggested by UI Browser):

```
select UI element 7 of group 2 of group 1 of window "myPDF.pdf"
```

You will get a little bit further using Acrobat JavaScript. As every button also has an internal menu item, you can use execMenuItem() to execute it. The problem is to find the correct name of the menu item. For that you may have to go back to Acrobat 9 or 8, and run listMenuItems from the Console.

And now, I leave away a lengthy rant about Acrobat's user interface(s)…

Comment: Tanks Max, still can't access those buttons, but you point me to excellent tool "UI Browser" which helps write applescript much quicker. Thanks!!!

Comment: You're welcome, and you actually came to the same conclusion about UI Browser as I did for my current work on Lightroom. You might actually look at an answer to the clicking problem I had there in this message: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26235153/applescript-lightroom-5-action-axshowmenu-in-smart-collection-panel-does-not