# AppleScript, Smile: Applescript run from Terminal works, same script called from a Smile dialog does not

Tags: dialog, applescript, lightroom

I am working on an automatization tool for Lightroom 5, using AppleScript (and a lot of UI scripting using System Events). I am using a Smile dialog as control script (although, it is planned to eventually create a control application using Swift).

I have a script which is supposed to import a set of Smart Collections. In order to do so, I am using UI scripting, plus a the "realClick" utility (written in Python) given as answer [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26235153/applescript-lightroom-5-action-axshowmenu-in-smart-collection-panel-does-not) .

If I run the script from AppleScript Editor, it works as intended. If I run the script from the Terminal (using the osascript syntax and the correct list of arguments), it works as intended.

But when I call it from the Smile control script

```
set myScript to "osascript path/to/script arg1 arg2"
do shell script myScript
```

the script starts to work, but when it comes to the UI scripting part, and the clicking, nothing happens.

I can't see any reasonable reason why this does not work. Probably I miss something simple.

I am running OSX 10.9.5, the newest version of Lightroom (via CC), and Smile version 3.8.0, build 845.

In the past, I have not been able to get in touch with anyone at Smile support at SatImage; maybe I was not trying the right channel, so, from there I have no help so far.

Any comment, hint, advice is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Update: I gave up on Smile, and am now migrating what I have to XCode / ASOC. The first tests were successful, and things appear to be faster to me.

Comment: The last time I had a question regarding Smile (which I always use), I was told to use the Smile Users List. It was not very helpful, however. In the past there was much better help and active development for Smile. If you haven't already, see this page: http://www.satimage.fr/software/en/support/troubleshooting.html

Comment: Regarding your specific problem: Try to simplify the script and post specific code. It is hard to know what could be wrong ... there may be a bug with how the process comes to the front before the clicking (how it activates) OR it may even be a security issue; make sure Smile is given Accessibility access in the Sys. Prefs. Privacy settings

Answer (score 0):

idea #1: check the security/privacy/accessibility settings

[image]

Comment: That is definitely something to check because it can be forgotten so easily. Smile has access to the machine.